# Acessing and positioning divs with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code with a div that contains 4 additional divs:

```
 <body>

 <div id="main">
   <div class="one">

   </div>
   <div class="two">

   </div>
   <div class="three">

   </div>
   <div class="four">

   </div>
 </div>

 </body>
```

How can I access the 4 divs inside and position them on the page to my liking with css?

The layout I'm going for is something like this:

[image]

I've been trying to google this but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Check bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: In a css file or tag you can identify elements with the id or class selector among many others. The `.` precedes class names and the `#` precedes id names. Defining the style for say you fourth inner div would look like the following: `.four { /*style attributes*/ }`; defining style for you main div could look like this: `div#main { /*style in here */ }`.

Comment: Please check daeto I have posted an answer probably it may helpful to you.

Comment: If you downvote an answer then can you give me an explanation of downvote?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the best understanding of your question, I tried to give you an answer.

```css
section {}

.main {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto 13%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.section1 {
  width: 40%;
}

.section2 {
  width: 40%;
}

.section1,
.section2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
}

.section3 {
  padding: 0px;
  /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 83%;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  height: 20%;
}

.section1 .inner-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.section2 .inner-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.section2 .inner-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.section3 .inner-1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <section class="section1">
    <div class="inner-1">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section2">
    <div class="inner-1"></div>
    <div class="inner-2"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="section3">
    <div class="inner-1"></div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Hope it may helpful to you.